# Pass argument in selector of right bar button item

Tags: objective-c, ios, selector

I have this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *donebutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = donebutton;
```

Now I want to pass some argument to the method :

```
- (void)doneButtonPressed{}
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **setAssociatedObject** for this if u want to pass object say string then:

Firstly add

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

Now

```
NSString *strText = @"text";

 objc_setAssociatedObject(donebutton, "Argument", strText, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); // provide button , key , object for passing
```

and retrieve like this where ever u want your arguments:

```
NSString *str = objc_getAssociatedObject(donebutton, "Argument"); //using button and key
//remove object associated for button if not needed.
```

But if u want button reference then

```
- (void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender{
  UIButton *btnClicked = (UIButton *)sender;
  .......
}
```

Comment: wow,looks like a magic :)) unfortunately i've spent all my votes for today(

Comment: btw, Price how to use it? if just copy and paste your code it gives warning like:
""implicit declaration of function...

Comment: wanted to ask should I import something but you have already answered. Also - there are 4 parameters in the set function, aren't there?

Comment: solved the problem by doing so:
objc_setAssociatedObject(self.btn, "theKey", strText, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
is that right?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly. You should store your parameter in an object elsewhere in your class, then retrieve it when you tap the button.

For example, if you want to pass a NSString, add one in your .h :

```
@interface myClass {

    NSString *param;
}
```

And in your .m :

```
- (void)doneButtonPressed {

    // Do something with param
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as you stated a selector like:

```
@selector(doneButtonPressed:)
```

it will crash because your method looks like:

```
- (void)doneButtonPressed{}
```

But should be:

```
- (void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender{}
```

You can pass your data through sender's tag for example...

Comment: +1, getting the parameter by sender's tag is the best in this situation, I think.

Answer (score 0):

A little hack that can be used in the case of **UIBarButtonItem** is to use the **possibleTitles** property which is actually a type of **NSSet < NSSString * >** which means you can store NSString in it to retrieve it later.

Here is how it can be done:

```
UIBarButtonItem * rightButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(presentNextSegue:) ];
rightButtonItem.possibleTitles = [NSSet setWithObject:@"SegueName"];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButtonItem;

-(void)presentNextSegue:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender {
   NSLog(@"%@",sender.possibleTitles.allObjects.firstObject);
}
```

**Note:** The actual use of **possibleTitles** property is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1038292/968848). This is just a tiny hack :)